# How to fix "InvalidValueError" in Angular 6

Tags: angular, google-maps

I'm using Angular 6 to initiate google map with directions using Google Maps directions API. After I implement the code. the console says the following error:

**Uncaught (in promise) 
Jc {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Jc (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…F5xxXLWf2ZqIDEfUDitY7Ncs&callback=initMap:123:108"}
message
:
"initMap is not a function"
name
:
"InvalidValueError"**

home.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../resources/css/style.min.css', '../../resources/css/bt.min.css']
})

// declare var calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) : any;

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    initMap() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var onChangeHandler = function() {
            this.calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
        document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    }

    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
            origin: (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('start')).value,
            destination: (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('end')).value,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } 
            else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
    }

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initMap();
    }

}
```

I have no idea why is this error message. Can anyone help?

Comment: Use AGM :: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@agm/core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this error occurs due to the presence of `callback` parameter while loading Google Maps JavaScript API:

```
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Since your map is getting initialized via `ngOnInit` lifecycle method, the callback parameter could be abandoned from url.

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bz2bdu) which demonstrates how to utilize Google Maps Directions Service with Angular2+ application